# How to stop CustomEvent "Activity" being logged in AppInsights - Enterprise Bot Enterprise

Tags: botframework, azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service

I'm setting up an enterprise bot template to experiment to explore the telemetry/analytics. The telemetry client by default logs custom events such as MessageSend, MessageReceive as well as LUIS/QnA Maker results.

In addition there are also a lot of logs for a plain customEvent "Activity" which I want to remove since I don't think it adds too much more information.

I have tried looking through the code and searching for the keyword "activity" which is quite a common word but haven't had any success in identifying what is logging the "Activity" custom events.

What would be the best way to remove it whilst still retaining the other events?

It would be really preferred over filtering out all the "Activity" custom events from the AppInsights side.

This is an example entry from AppInsights

```
2019-04-15T08:38:12.663
Activity
customEvent
{"EventName":"Activity","Conversation ID":"KYCWjfhXcKKeR7vt0U5Kw-1","Correlation ID":"|8317ccf735770f44afcaacd529bf5f04.99baaf0a_99baaf10_",
"Activity type":"conversationUpdate",
"Activity ID":"L1gCaQC3Qx7",
"StatusCode":"500",
"Channel ID":"webchat",
"Timestamp":"2019-04-14T22:37:57.6457876Z"} .... more columns
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> In addition there are also a lot of logs for a plain customEvent
>   "Activity" which I want to remove since I don't think it adds too much
>   more information.

Are you really sure about that? An activity is the general word for a message in Bot Framework. A text message, an event message, etc. All the exchanges between your user in his/her channel and your bot on your backend (through the Bot Connector) is an `Activity`.

So it is the main / most important information that will allow you to understand and review a previous conversation.

If your problem is about `Activity` of type `Event`, I also highly suggest that you keep those activities logged as it is just a question of filtering on your display: you'd better have all the details rather than filtering some. In the future, I think you may be happy to find out why you did not had such or such behaviour in your bot, and that may be due to this kind of Activity

Comment: Hi, thanks, those are fair points, it would be good to have some extra logging but I am still interested in knowing how the activity logging is done as in the enterprise bot template. There seems to be two wrappers for LUIS and QnA Maker services which uses a telemetry client to log but I can't seem to find where the "activity" custom event logs are being generated and uploaded in the sample. Thanks